# Prevent domain owner from appearing next to site title

Tags: google-search, web-search

My company hosts a web application purchased from a third party company. This website is a generic content management site in which we handle content for multiple clients. My company owns root domain events.jspargo.com

When someone searches for the title of one of our sites, the search results display the correct site title, but then appends our company name next to it.

Nothing in any of our meta tags or page attributes is specifying our company name so I'm not sure why/how our company name is displayed next to the site title. I'm guessing maybe it's automatic because we are the owner of the domain.

I've read online docs pertaining to robots.txt etc but I can't see that any of that documentation references exactly what I'm trying to do.

My goal is to NOT have our company name appear next to the title, because the title is specific to our client's information and they don't want our company name in the search results.

Example #1: If you search for "West 2015" the first result is "2015 West - J. Spargo & Associates". The "2015 West" is the title of our site and the "J. Spargo & Associates" is the name of our company. Nothing in the site is specifying reference to "J. Spargo & Associates" and our client does not want our company name next to their show name. They want the result to only show "2015 West"

Example #2: If you search for "Technet 2015" the first result is "2015 TechNet Augusta - J. Spargo & Associates". Same issue... we don't want our company name "J. Spargo & Associates" to appear next to the site title "2015 TechNet Augusta"

Can anyone provide clear information as to how to get rid of that specific item in the search result?

Comment: I guess if there was a way to override this value that would be acceptable as well. For example if there was a way to specifically set a meta tag, so that the value of the meta tag would display instead of our company name, we could do that as well, rather than trying to just remove our company name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research and playing around I determined that the reason the domain owner appeared next to the title in the search results was because the titles of the sites in question were too generic. Because multiple sites returned the same title, the search engine automatically displayed the additional information to allow the viewer of the results to have a better idea of the differences between the like titled results.

To "fix" this issue, simply update the title tag of your site(s) to be more unique.

Example:
Site 1 (owned by WidgetMakers.com) title = "My Widgets"
Site 2 (owned by GadgetGoGetters.ord) title = "My Widgets"

Search results:
(Site 1 reads as): My Widgets - WidgetMakers.com
(Site 2 reads as): My Widgets - GadgetGoGetters.org

Change to:
Site 1 (owned by WidgetMakers.com) title = "My Widgets made by WidgetMakers!"
Site 2 (owned by GadgetGoGetters.ord) title = "Cool Widgets are My Widgets"

Search Results
(Site 1 reads as): My Widgets made by WidgetMakers!
(Site 2 reads as): My Widgets - Cool Widgets are My Widgets

So having a unique title for your sites will prevent additional description information from being added automatically by search engines.